# Python json.loads error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:

Tags: python, json

I've used Insomnia to send a json file ('json_information') to app django.

```
{
"company": 2,
"value": 0.15,
"date": "2020-01-01",
"default": "False",
"active": "False",
"list": [
{
"sku": "A1B2C3",
},
{
"sku": "D4E5F6",
},
{
"sku": "G7H8I9",
},
{
"sku": "J0K1L2",
},
],
}
```

The python code to load this json fails:

```
data = json.loads(request.data['json_information'], strict=False)
```

The error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 11 column 1 (char 181)
```

Any idea?

Comment: The trailing commas make the JSON invalid

Comment: That's not json. How was the string creatred?

Comment: It is valid python. JSON and python literals are a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing commas are not supported by the json module.

```
{
"company": 2,
"value": 0.15,
"date": "2020-01-01",
"default": "False",
"active": "False",
"list": [
{
"sku": "A1B2C3", <-- This one
},
{
"sku": "D4E5F6", <-- This one
},
{
"sku": "G7H8I9", <-- This one
},
{
"sku": "J0K1L2", <-- This one
}, <-- This one
], <-- This one
}
```

See [this other answers](http://%7B%20%22company%22:%202,%20%22value%22:%200.15,%20%22date%22:%20%222020-01-01%22,%20%22default%22:%20%22False%22,%20%22active%22:%20%22False%22,%20%22list%22:%20%5B%20%7B%20%22sku%22:%20%22A1B2C3%22,%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22sku%22:%20%22D4E5F6%22,%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22sku%22:%20%22G7H8I9%22,%20%7D,%20%7B%20%22sku%22:%20%22J0K1L2%22,%20%7D,%20%5D,%20%7D) for alternatives